# what is the advantage of lucene's Compound File

Tags: lucene

what is diference between a single file like lucene's Compound File and muti file for dependent index type?

Answer (score 4):

it uses less files to keep the index, so it can help avoid the [Too many open files](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-4) issue (that in unix you handle with ulimit).

It is also slower.

Comment: Did you mean processing Compound Files is slow? Can you point me to some good references which talk about it?